# Login jQuery Mysql debug

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

My little script isn't working, I can't figure this out...

If you echo 'true'; on check.php it works otherwise it doesn't

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").hide();
        $.post("check.php", { username: $("#username").val(), password: $("#password").val() }, function(result) {
            if(result == "true") { $("#submit").show(); }});
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
        Username <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
        Password <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

check.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', '', '');
mysql_select_db('database');
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "',password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'")) > 0)
    {
        echo "true";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "false";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You have a comma in your `WHERE` it should be `AND` e.g. `WHERE username = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "' AND password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'")) > 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in MYSQL you have `,` instead of `AND`

Should read:

```
"' AND password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])
```

Not:

```
"', password = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])
```

Answer (score 0):

in your callback you have `if(result == "true")` This is why you have to echo 'true' ?